# Git : git status don't show new files and git add return fatal file is outside repository

Tags: git, repository

I created new files in my project and git status return 
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

When i try to add new files with git add , i have 
fatal: file is outside repository.

But when a make change in other old files , git status track change and i can commit it.

Comment: Are you sure you're adding files inside the project's directory?

Comment: yes, i add the file in project directory,

Comment: Speculation... Could there be a symlinked directory involved? Maybe try to `cd` to the directory containing the file and run commands: `pwd` and `readlink -f .`. Do they return the same path?

Comment: The problem is in my gitignore file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check if your file is ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```

Second, that error message ("`is outside repository`") will be clarified with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020).

See [commit e0020b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0020b2f82910f50bc697d86aff70c3796fbdc41) (15 Feb 2020) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f97741f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f97741f6e9c46a75b4322760d77322e53c4322d7), 17 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`prefix_path`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0020b2f82910f50bc697d86aff70c3796fbdc41): show `gitdir` when arg is outside repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>
>   <sup>Acked-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> When developing a script, it can be painful to understand why Git thinks something is outside the current repo, if the current repo isn't what the user thinks it is.
>
> Since this can be tricky to diagnose, especially in cases like submodules or nested worktrees, let's give the user a hint about which repository is offended about that path.

The error message will then be:

```
aFile is outside repository at 'full/path/of/repo'
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   (new!)
```

---

And, still with Git 2.25.2 (March 2020), the update above, to show the location of working tree in the error message, did not consider the possibility that a `git` command may be run in a bare repository, which has been corrected.

See [commit 5c20398](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c20398699165a91af2d81ea2d20385bc8dd3627) (03 Mar 2020) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e96327c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e96327c94799460e02b38b242995eab0600ebbd6), 16 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`prefix_path`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c20398699165a91af2d81ea2d20385bc8dd3627): show gitdir if worktree unavailable
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer
>
>   [jc: added minimum tests, with help from Szeder Gábor]
>
>   Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>
> If there is no worktree at present, we can still hint the user about Git's current directory by showing them the absolute path to the Git directory. Even though the Git directory doesn't make it as easy to locate the worktree in question, it can still help a user figure out what's going on while developing a script.
>
> This fixes a segmentation fault introduced in [e0020b2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0020b2f82910f50bc697d86aff70c3796fbdc41) ("`prefix_path`: show `gitdir` when `arg` is outside repo", 2020-02-14).